# Init query (.where / .order) with empty query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to do something like:

```
if filter_1
  @field = @field.where()
else
  @field = @field.where()
end

if filter_2
  @field = @field.order()
end

etc.
```

But how do I init `@field` with an empty query? I tried `@field = Field.all` but that gives an array so not allowing chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `scoped`on Model class e.g.

```
@fields =  Field.scoped
@fields = @fields.where("your conditions") if filter_1
@fields = @fiels.order("your conditions") if filter_2
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you are initializing the @field instance variable, Please try referring to the class Field, i.e.

Filter1: `@field = Field.where(...)`

Afterwards if you need to keep adding further filters you can refer to your variable field as many times as you want to.

Filter2 onward: `@field = @field.where(...)`

As Filter1 would return an active Record relation, you can nest more condition clauses onto it. Also do not worry about performance issues as the SQL will only be generated and processed once it is actually needed.(lazy loading)

If you to @field.to_sql at the end of your filters, you'll be able to see that all of your where clauses have conveniently been nested together into one SQL statement.

Also, I'd recommend you to read [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

EDIT

Create a method get_field. And use that to add filter results.

```
def get_field(field)  
  @field.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation) ? Field : field
end


get_field(@field).where(....) 
get_field(@field).where(....)
```

Comment: I cannot know which line will first initialize the query as the "if filter" may make you jump queries.

Comment: Aaah. Please look at my edit. Hopefully that will help you. Let me know if you need any further explanation.